# How to properly configure Nginx Proxy Manager with Docker containers?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm starting using Docker locally to host some web based application for home usage (paperless-ngx, MagicMirror, etc) and I manage all of them via dockge container.

Now, just for the sake of curiosity/learning, I'd like to expose those application on the web to be able to use them form anywhere I am but obviously I'm setting something wrong because when trying to access the default container fomr the web i get a 502 error with the only description 'openresty'.

##### What I've done so far:

- forwarded ports 80 and 443 to my pc in my router
- set up dynamic dns with a free subdomain on noip.com, it is XXXX.ddns.net
- in NPM I set up a proxy host for XXXX.ddns.net do redirect it to the MagicMirror container:

  - it has a free Let's Encrypt certificate
  - it redirects to https://192.168.1.109:8080 (my pc ip, but using 'localhost' gives the same result/error)
  - I didn't set any other option
- in dockge conainer added the NPM netowrk to the MM container

##### MagicMirror docker compose:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  magicmirror:
    image: karsten13/magicmirror:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./mounts/config:/opt/magic_mirror/config
      - ./mounts/modules:/opt/magic_mirror/modules
      - ./mounts/css:/opt/magic_mirror/css
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - npm
      - run
      - server
networks:
  nginx-proxy-manager_default:
    external: true
```

##### The error

when visiting XXXX.ddns.net the page loads almost instantly with the 502 error, so it seems to reach NPM correctly, but somenthing in my configuration is wrong.